# border-radius table visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, css, renderas, styleclass

I am trying to put some styling to my table with a border-radius in my visualforce page but when rendered to pdf I dont see the rounded corners. Is this not possible with render to PDF and if not are there any suggestions to get rounded forms in render to pdf?

I tried:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black; border-radius:50px">
```

and

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote" renderAs="advanced_pdf" cache="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">

    <html>
        <head> 
        <style type="text/css" media="print">
                .rcorners1 {
                                    border-radius: 50px;
                                    border: 2px solid #000;
                                    padding: 20px; 
                                    width: 200px;
                                    height: 150px;    
                                    }
                </style>
        </head>    
    <body>        
            <p class="rcorners1">..</p>
    </body>  
    <html>
</apex:page>
```

If anyone wants to try this for a solution:

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote" renderAs="advanced_pdf" cache="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                .rcorners1 {
                border-radius: 50px;
                border: 2px solid #000;
                padding: 20px; 
                width: 200px;
                height: 150px;    
                }
                @media print {
                border-radius: 50px;
                border: 2px solid #000;
                padding: 20px; 
                width: 200px;
                height: 150px;   
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table style="border: 1px solid black; border-radius:50px">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        test
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p class="rcorners1">Lets look if this works</p>
        </body>
    </html>    
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Have you tried to put your style tag inside your <head></head> tag ? :)

Comment: @FabienHuot I currenty have them between head tags but its not working I updated the info with what i have

Comment: @Latifa I updated my answer, please check if it is related to css3

Comment: Are your other css styles affecting the pdf?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your style tag within the head tag.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is because your new window can't understand your CSS style (media=print)
can you try add something like this :

```
<style>
@media print {
 border-radius: 50px;
 border: 2px solid #000;
 padding: 20px; 
 width: 200px;
 height: 150px;   
}
</style>
```

Comment: I tried all of the above but its still not working if I remove the render as ik get rounded corners only for the  <p class="rcorners1">..</p>
part. Seems like I will have to be working with an image as background

Answer (score -1):

Have you done these things:

> If you use inline CSS styles, set the API version to 28.0 or later.
>   Also set `<apex:page applyBodyTag="false">`, and add static, valid
>   `<head> and <body>` tags to your page, as in the previous example.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_considerations.htm

Are your other css styles affecting the pdf?

Since border-radius is css3, please check if this [change from summer 17](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_vf_advanced_pdf.htm) works for you:

```
renderAs="advanced_pdf"
```

Comment: Yes I did. I also updated my input to show what I already tried in case anyone else wants to do further research